# I need to reassign values before missing to the last element (before the missing value) in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, missing-data

For example let's say I have this data.

```
 data have;
   input end;
   datalines;
1
2
4
5
.
4
8
6
.
1
2
3
.
;
```

I want it to look like this 5,5,5,5,.,6,6,6,.,3,3,3.

I've tried this.

```
data want;
   set have;
   array end_array(*) end;
   do i = dim(end_array) to 2 by -1;
      if not missing(end_array[i]) and not missing(end_array[i-1]) then
         end_array[i-1] = end_array[i];
   end;
   output; /* output entire modified end_array to the output dataset */
run;
```

Essentially I want to start from the end and loop backwards. If both values are not missing replace the value behind the previous one. Stop the loop at the 2nd element (so it doesn't crash i-1 after i=1).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 data have;
   input end;
   datalines;
1
2
4
5
.
4
8
6
.
1
2
3
.
;

data want(drop = e);
   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (end = .);
      set have;
      if end then e = end;
   end;
   
   do _N_ = 1 to _N_;
      set have;
      if end then end = e;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: This is very cool. I need to analyze this to find out exactly what's going on. This is a really clever solution.

Comment: @Stu hearing that from you means a lot :-)

Comment: My solution had multiple data and sorting steps, but yours is all in one! It's fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

And sure you can do it with array.

```
data want;
  array end_array[13];
  do i=1 by 1 until(eof);
    set have end=eof;
    end_array[i]=end;
  end;

  do i=dim(end_array) to 1 by -1;
    if end_array[i]=. then tmp=.;
    else do;
      if tmp=. then tmp=end_array[i];
      end_array[i]=tmp;
    end;
  end;
run;
```